# Running Spring Boot(Maven) WebApp on external tomcat 8.5

Tags: spring-boot

trying to run spring-boot web app which returns jsp page as response

controller code is :

```
public class IndexCtrl {

    @RequestMapping(value="home")
    public String example() {        
        return "test.jsp";
    }   
}
```

in pom.xml tomcat-jasper dependency has been added.

> ERROR 6352 --- [nio--exec-X]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Cannot forward to error
>   page for request [] as the response has already been
>   committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
>   If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may
>   be able to resolve this problem by setting
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

Answer (score 0):

Change @RequestMapping(value="home") to @RequestMapping("/home") it worked for me in spring-boot version 2.2.5.RELEASE